# Tensor operator analogy in classical physics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, tensor-calculus, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In quantum mechanics, [tensor operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator) are defined through their commutation with the operators of spherical angular momentum components,
$$\begin{aligned} \
[L_3,T(k,q)] &= \hbar q\ T(k,q), \\
[L_\pm,T(k,q)] &= \hbar \alpha^\pm(k,q)\ T(k,q\pm1).
\end{aligned}$$
This can be equivalently rewritten in Cartesian coordinates, e.g., a vector operator $(V_i)_{i=1}^3$ needs to satisfy
$$[L_j, V_k] = i\hbar\ \epsilon_{jkl} V_l.$$
This is nicer in that it only uses self-adjoint observables. **What I am wondering about is what this corresponds to in classical Poissonian mechanics**, where an analogous condition would be
$$\{L_j,V_k\} = \epsilon_{jkl} V_l \label{1}\tag{1}$$
for three phase-space functions $(V_1, V_2, V_3)$. Of course we all know that components of position, momentum, or angular momentum satisfy this, but I want to see a general solution.

What I have tried is rewrite (\ref{1}) as
$$\{\epsilon_{jmn}x_mp_n, V_k\} = \epsilon_{jmn}\frac{\partial V_k}{\partial p_m}p_n - \epsilon_{jmn}x_m\frac{\partial V_k}{\partial x_n} = \epsilon_{jkl} V_l,\quad \forall j,$$
multiply both sides by the $j$-th component of a generic normal vector $\vec n$ and a generic displacement $\chi$ and interpret the left-hand side as the first-order term in a Taylor expansion,
$$V_k(x_n - \chi \epsilon_{jmn}n_j x_m, p_m + \chi \epsilon_{jmn}n_j p_n) = V_k(x_n, p_m) + \chi n_j \epsilon_{jkl} V_l(x_n, p_m) + O(\chi^2),$$
where $V_k(x_n,p_m)$ is a shortcut for $V_k(x_1,x_2,x_3,p_1,p_2,p_3)$, or $V_k(\vec x, \vec p)$. This can be exponentiated to get
$$V_k\big(\exp(-\chi n_j \epsilon_{j\bullet\bullet})_{mn} x_m,\,\exp(\chi n_j \epsilon_{j\bullet\bullet})_{mn} p_n\big) = \exp(\chi n_j \epsilon_{j\bullet\bullet})_{kl} V_l(x_n,p_m).$$
The exponentials now denote rotational matrices about $\vec n$ by the angle $\pm\chi$,
$$\exp(\pm \chi n_j \epsilon_{j\bullet\bullet})_{mn} = R(\vec n,\pm \chi)_{mn},$$
so we obtain that $\vec V = (V_1, V_2, V_3)$ must satisfy
$$\vec V(R(\vec n,-\chi)^T \vec x, R(\vec n,\chi)\vec p) = R(\vec n,\chi) \vec V(\vec x, \vec p).$$
We also use the orthogonality of $R$,
$$R(\vec n,-\chi)^T = R(\vec n,-\chi)^{-1} = R(\vec n,\chi) =: R,$$
so
$$\vec V(R \vec x, R \vec p) = R \vec V(\vec x, \vec p).$$

Denoting $\vec{\tilde{x}} = R \vec{x}$ and $\vec{\tilde{p}} = R \vec{p}$, we get
$$\vec V(\vec{\tilde{x}}, \vec{\tilde{p}}) = R \vec V(R^{-1} \vec{\tilde{x}}, R^{-1} \vec{\tilde{p}}).$$
Now the arguments in the right-hand side are $\vec x$, $\vec p$ computed back from $\vec{\tilde{x}}$, $\vec{\tilde{p}}$, fed into the untransformed $\vec V$, and covariantly (NB: no difference between covariant and contravariant in $SO(3)$) transformed to the tilde basis. This is exactly the full transformation rule of a vector field, so the RHS equals $\vec{\tilde{V}}(\vec{\tilde{x}}, \vec{\tilde{p}})$, or
$$\vec V(\vec{\tilde{x}}, \vec{\tilde{p}}) = \vec{\tilde{V}}(\vec{\tilde{x}}, \vec{\tilde{p}}). \label{2}\tag{2}$$
This would mean that the functions $(V_k)_{k=1}^3$ satisfy (\ref{1}) if and only if treating them as a vector field and transforming to a rotated basis would be the same as only plugging the *transformed coordinates* into the *original (untransformed) functions*, or that their functional form is *invariant* under vector field rotation. This seems to be a quite strong condition that not many things I used to call vector fields would satisfy. 
For example, take a constant vector field, say, $\vec V(\vec r, \vec p) = (0, 0, -g)^T$. In a rotated basis the transform rules dictate $\vec{\tilde{V}}(\vec{\tilde{r}}, \vec{\tilde{p}}) = R\cdot(0,0,-g)^T$, which in general are different three constants than $0$, $0$ and $-g$. So (\ref{2}) is broken, which is consistent with the fact that a Poisson bracket of the form (\ref{1}) with a constant $V_k$ is zero, rather than $\epsilon_{jkl}V_l$.

An example of $(V_k)_{k=1}$ that does conform to (\ref{1}) are the canonical projections
$$\begin{aligned}
V_1(x, y, z, p_x, p_y, p_z) &= x, \\
V_2(x, y, z, p_x, p_y, p_z) &= y, \\
V_3(x, y, z, p_x, p_y, p_z) &= z \\
\end{aligned}$$
(as is well known), and indeed transforming the radius vector $\vec r = (V_1, V_2, V_3) = (x,y,z)$ gives $\vec{\tilde{r}} = (\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z)$, whose components are the first three elements of the tuple $(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z)$, so
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde V_1(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z) &= \tilde x = V_1(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z), \\
\tilde V_2(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z) &= \tilde y = V_2(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z), \\
\tilde V_3(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z) &= \tilde z = V_3(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z, \tilde p_x, \tilde p_y, \tilde p_z) \\
\end{aligned}$$

**So the "classical vector observable" is something stricter than a "vector field" over phase space, requiring that the *functions* defining its components stay intact under rotations** (or $GL$ transforms, as could be shown analogously). What are such special vector fields called? Or am I missing something in my derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement $\tilde{V}(x,p)=V(x,p)$ is simply that the vector field be rotationally symmetric. Rotational symmetry clearly holds for $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)$ (just picture is in your head), and you can convince yourself that it holds for angular momentum in phase space.

In Hamiltonian mechanics, the Poisson bracket makes the smooth functions $C^\infty(M)$ on phase space into a Lie algebra. The angular momenta then furnish a Lie algebra representation of the rotation group $\{L_i,L_j\}=\epsilon_{ijk}L_k$. You can check that the action of the $L_i$ on functions $f\in C^\infty(M)$ is just the infinitesimal version of the $O(3)$ representation $f\to f\circ R^{-1}$, where I've used $R(x,p)=(Rx,Rp)$ for short. This should, of course, not be confused with the $O(3)$ action on vector fields $V^i\mapsto R^i_j \cdot(V^j\circ R^{-1})$.

Lastly, note that 'proper' quantum vector fields carry a position index $V^j=V^j(x)$. They $\textbf{don't}$ satisfy $[J_i,V_j(x)]=i\epsilon_{ijk} V_k(x)$ unless $x=0$. The usual vector operators in quantum mechanics correspond not to vector fields, but to single vectors.

Comment: How simple – I'm feeling very stupid right now :-) Would one still use some variation on the term "rotationally symmetric" if this property is held (as it is the case for $\vec r$ transformed as a contravariant or $\vec p$ as a covariant quantity) for a general $S \in GL(3)$? I can't think of any.

Comment: Suppose we have some $V(x)$ such that $V(x)=A V(A^{-1}x)$ for any $A\in\text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$. Then, we have $V(\hat{z})=V(R(\theta)\hat{z})=R(\theta)V(\hat{z})$ where $R(\theta)$ is any rotation in the $x$-$y$ plane. This gives $V(\hat{z})=\lambda \hat{z}$ for some scalar $\lambda$. From this one obtains $V(x)=\lambda x$ in general. These fields are not just rotationally symmetric, they're proportional to $\vec{x}$.